# xcode swift - sending vector image to server

Tags: xcode, vector, swift

is it possible to send an UIImage in some vector format to an php server, and how would it be done? It's important that the image would be in some vector format.

I have created an app where you can draw lines, I would like to save those drawn lines to an image in some vector format. I say some, becouse I'm not sure what format is the best. 
I just need to be able to save to it and read it.

Here is my code for drawing.

```
@IBAction func panning(sender: AnyObject) {
    pan.maximumNumberOfTouches = 1;
    pan.minimumNumberOfTouches = 1;

    var currentPoint:CGPoint = pan.locationInView(self);
    var midPoint:CGPoint = midpoint(previousPoint, p1: currentPoint);

    if(pan.state == UIGestureRecognizerState.Began){
        path.moveToPoint(currentPoint);
    } else if (pan.state == UIGestureRecognizerState.Changed){
        path.addQuadCurveToPoint(midPoint, controlPoint: previousPoint);

    }

    path.lineCapStyle = kCGLineCapRound;
    path.lineWidth = 10;

    previousPoint = currentPoint;

    self.setNeedsDisplay();




}

override func drawRect(rect: CGRect) {

    //println(pan.velocityInView(self));

    UIColor.redColor().setStroke();


    path.stroke();

}

@IBAction func sendImage(sender: AnyObject) {

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.bounds.size);
    var ctx:CGContextRef = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    self.layer.renderInContext(ctx);
    var saveImg = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();

    UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(saveImg, self, Selector("image:didFinishSavingWithError:contextInfo:"), nil);

    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();


}

func image(image: UIImage, didFinishSavingWithError error: NSErrorPointer, contextInfo: UnsafePointer<()>) {
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
        UIAlertView(title: "Success", message: "This image has been saved to your Camera Roll successfully", delegate: nil, cancelButtonTitle: "Close").show()
    })
}

func midpoint(p0:CGPoint, p1:CGPoint)->CGPoint{

    var retCG:CGPoint = CGPoint(x: (p0.x + p1.x) / 2.0, y: (p0.y + p1.y) / 2.0);

    return retCG;

}
```

Thanks.

Comment: This is far too broad. http://whathaveyoutried.com Converting from a raster-based `UIImage` to "some vector format" is a major undertaking. Of course some vector formats may let you embed the whole raster image, but I assume that's not what you want. You need to narrow down this question to more specifics (probably start with what vector format you want, and what kind of images you're trying to convert to vector).

Comment: Ferenc, is your question about _convering an `UIImage` to vector format_ **or** _sending a custom type of data to a server_?

Comment: I just edited the question